# struct * and char * segmentation fault on malloc

Tags: c, struct, char, segmentation-fault, malloc

Here is the code I am having a problem with:

Struct:

```
struct AtoB
{
    char * strA;
    char * strB;
};
```

Function to create the struct. Called from external file.

```
AtoB * atob_create(char * a)
{
    struct AtoB * atob = (struct AtoB *)malloc(sizeof(struct AtoB));
    atob->strA = malloc(sizeof((char *)a));
    strcpy(atob->strA, a);

    atob->strB = NULL;
    /* HERE IS PROBLEM NO 1 - SEGMENTATION ERROR OCCURS */
    atob->strB = (char*)malloc(1);
    strB = "\0";

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(atob->strA); i++)
    {
        char token = atob->strA[i];
        /*
        : 
            append(AtoB * atob, const char a) MAY be called, so atob->strB &
            atob->StrA will not be the same length 
        */
        append(atob, (char)token);
    }
}
```

Function to append a `char` to the `char *` within the `struct`. Called recursively.

```
void append(AtoB * atob, const char a)
{
    size_t sz = strlen(atob->strB);
    /* HERE IS ANOTHER ISSUE:
       1: is this the right way to increase the size of the char * ?
       2: does the struct also need to be realloc here to accommodate? 
    */
    atob->strB = (char*)realloc(atob->strB, sz + 1);
    atob->strB[sz - 1 = a];
    atob->[sz] = "\0";
}
```

Function to retrieve the final string. Called from external file.

```
char * (AtoB * atob)
{
    return (atob->strB);
}
```

Function to free all the allocated memory. Called from external file.

```
void free(AtoB * atob)
{
    free(atob->strA);
    free(atob->strB);
    free(atob);
}
```

As an exercise I am required to use C and take the content of one string, copying it in a different order or omitting or adding certain characters based on criteria that are not the issue here (therefore not included in the code).

I'm not having a problem creating the struct or allocating the first `char * strA`. The problem arises when I try to allocate memory (even one char) to `char * strB`.

I get a segmentation error.

It doesn't seem to matter how I try to do this, I have read up various examples and tried various ways and I just can't get it to work. I am aware there is some memory issue here but I can't seem to resolve it.

Even if I try to `realloc` the struct I can't get `strB` to be initialized to anything more than `NULL`. I need to be able to append to `atob->strB` at runtime, the final length of the string being different to the length of `atob->strA`.

Following examples online, I thought this (as the most simple initialization) would work... it doesn't though:

```
atob->strB = NULL;
atob->strB = (char*)malloc(1);
atob->strB[0]  "\0";
```

Is it something to do with the struct it's in?

I really can't get my head round what is wrong, have wasted much time searching for similar problems on various forums,  reading round the topic and trying every single solution I can just trying to get past this first issue.

Now I'm just confused and out of time to solve this. If someone can tell me the actual code that I need, then I will be able to read it and understand what you did and why that is the correct method. I have commented in the areas where I am not clear and would really appreciate the correct solution.

Comment: You don't need to type cast the call to malloc.  Most C++ programmers do this, and it isn't necessary.

Comment: can you use a debugger and show the back-trace of your crash?

Comment: Why downvote on this one? If the question lacks clarity ask the op to explain more.

Comment: I've done an example program which kinda simulate your situation. Check [\[ this \]](http://pastebin.com/raw/21dujd9p) piece of code.

Comment: @sjsam: at a guess, the downvote is for asking directly for the solution rather than for guidance towards a solution. Whilst this is not a gimme-teh-codez question, it is well worth avoiding sounding even slightly similar to such approaches!

Comment: @halfer hmm i kind of agree to what you said but this question shows a nice effort from a novice, the downvoter should have asked the op to reword. In any case, i am against downvoting without a feedback. 

Comment: @sjsam: I hear you, but that has been discussed a great deal on _Meta_, and the answer is that voters will never be forced by technical means to provide a comment or reason - voting will always be anonymous. However, I agree it would be nice for voters to offer a reason voluntarily!

Answer (score 2):

This code does not do what you think it does:

```
atob->strA = malloc(sizeof((char *)a));
                    ^ sizeof(char *) is fixed. probably 4 or 8.
```

So, if `a` points to a longer string, you will have a buffer overflow.

if you are using Linux, you better run valgrind memory checker to make sure you have no additional memory handling problems.

### Debugging information:

compile sure it is compiled with debug symbols (add -g to gcc command)

```
$ gcc -g -Wall -Werror a.c -o a.out
```

run it with gdb

```
$ gdb ./a.out
```

after the crash, look for backtrace

```
(gdb) bt
```

When you have it, just look where the crash is and try to understand why.

since we are dealing with memory handling problems, use valgrind:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

Look at the output and clean the errors.

Comment: sorry guys like i said i have read various topics, forums & followed examples & ended up with the code i have stated. It has changed many times via various forms. Why does the initial malloc (strA) work & the second (strB) doesn't, even if they are exactly the same (ie copy a into each)? Can you tell me what the code should be to allocate 1 char in char * strB & then how to add a char in the append function?

Comment: The error shown in terminal is simply 'received signal 11 (segmentation fault)

Comment: to debug:
- compile your program with -g to allow debug symbols

Comment: the make file contains CFLAGS = -std=c99 -c -g. & then compiles gcc $(CFLAGS). That is the only error that's being output to the terminal...

Comment: see my other answer about debugging

Comment: OK eyalm i'll try that

Comment: incidentally, even if    atob->strA = malloc(sizeof((char *)a));    strcpy(atob->strA, a);   is causing a buffer overflow, I have no idea how to remedy it... can anyone tell me? This is a method that I copied from an example, if it doesn't do what the example tells me, I am completely stumped! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `strB` to an empty string, you use:

```
strB = "\0";
```

But you should instead use either:

```
strB = '\0';
```

or:

```
strB[0] = '\0'.
```

The string literal `"\0"` is an array of three `chars`: `{'\', '0', '\0'}`. You do the same thing in other places (here it looks like you left out the name of the `struct` field):

```
atob->strB[sz] = "\0";
```

and (here I presume that you left out the assignment operator by accident):

```
atob->strB[0] = "\0";
```

There is an issue with the way that you grow the string. `strlen()` gives the number of `char`s in the array before the `NUL` terminator, so if you want to add another `char` you need to allocate for `sz + 2` `char`s. Then the new `char` needs to be placed at `strB[sz]`, which is where the old `NUL` was, and `NUL` needs to be placed at the end of the string, which is `strB[sz + 1]`.
You can `NUL` terminate the string `strB` by changing your code to:

```
atob->strB = realloc(atob->strB, sz + 2);
atob->strB[sz] = a;
atob->strB[sz + 1] = '\0';
```

Also, it is possible for `realloc()` to return `NULL`, causing a memory leak. You should use a temporary variable to store the result of the call to `realloc()`:

```
char *temp = realloc(atob->strB, sz + 2);
if (temp)
    atob->strB = temp;
```

Comment: yes David sorry that was a typo, it is atob->strB[sz] = "\0"; (am writing it in not copy pasting).

Comment: @eyalm - THANKYOU
    sizeof(char *) is fixed. probably 4 or 8.
I then understood it was actually failing BEFORE the allocation of strB...

Comment: @sjsam - your example makes complete sense & I now understand:
After eyalm’s explanation I saw strA was causing the issue, but I still couldn't figure how I was supposed to get the right length allocated.
    atob->strA=malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char)); "
I get it! strlen was just telling me how many lots of 4 bytes there were, not the actual amount required to be allocated in memory.
THANKYOU for your explanation & MORE IMPORTANTLY for reading my question & answering exactly what I asked.

Comment: @oblong-- note that you do not need to use `sizeof(char)` in `malloc`. A `char` is one byte, and `malloc()` allocates the number of bytes that you specify, so `malloc(1)` allocates space for 1 `char`. It is in fact considered bad practice to use `sizeof(char)` in a call to `malloc()`.

Comment: hi @David, thanks for that - but then how do you allocate space if you don't know how much you would want until runtime? i.e. in the case of 'a' being of unknown length, how does 
    atob->strA=malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char)); 
get performed if you weren't using chars? or is it only available for chars? i.e. can you use it for an array of ints?

Comment: @oblong-- a `char` is guaranteed to be 1 byte, so if you need to allocate for `n` `char`s you use `malloc(n)`. To allocate for `int`s, then you use the `sizeof()` operator: `malloc(sizeof(int) * n)`. It is simply redundant to use `sizeof(char)` here.

Comment: got you... thanks David, sjsam & eyalm. I understand what I'm doing & why now, especially with sjsam's example which made it clear & now the code is working exactly as required.